# CI tools to prevent forgetting to change code

Tags: git

Suppose you have multiple Git repositories, and you have a dependency that if you change code A(a) in one repository A, you must change code B(a) in another repository B.

In this situation, how can you check for forgotten changes before git pushing? Or is there already a good tool for this?

I am in the process of writing a tool for this problem myself and would like to know if there are existing tools that could be applied to this problem.

Comment: CI would likely go after pushing. You'd also need to define the sequence of operations - should people update A(a) first, or should they update B(a) first, and what kind of delay is acceptable?

Comment: Assume that CI is performed on every commit

Comment: ...so it'd run based on what you're doing on your local machine?

Comment: Yes, I want a tool for local machines.